# I am trying to deserialize a JSON string using VB.NET 2.0

Tags: json, vb.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string and am stuck.

My string is

```
[{"BasketItemID":3,"ProductEmbellishmentID":8,"EmbellishmentText":"lfo","Price":9.95},{"BasketItemID":3,"ProductEmbellishmentID":3,"EmbellishmentText":"rc","Price":9.95}]
```

I have saved this in the string embels

My class is

```
Public Class Embellishments
Private _BasketItemID As Integer
Private _ProductEmbellishmentID As Integer
Private _EmbellishmentText As Integer
Private _Price As Integer


Public Property BasketItemID() As Integer
    Get
        Return _BasketItemID
    End Get

    Set(value As Integer)
        _BasketItemID = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property ProductEmbellishmentID() As String
    Get
        Return _ProductEmbellishmentID
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _ProductEmbellishmentID = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property EmbellishmentText() As String
    Get
        Return _EmbellishmentText
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _EmbellishmentText = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Price() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _Price
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        _Price = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

And I try to deserialize using

```
        Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim emblist As List(Of Embellishments) = jss.Deserialize(Of Embellishments)(embels)
```

But get the error Value of type 'Embellishments' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Embellishments)'

I am now stuck. Can anyone give me any pointers?
thanks

> EDIT

Thanks to @Plutonix I have now tried

```
    Dim errormessage As String=''
Dim Count As Integer = 0
Try
    Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim emblist As List(Of Embellishments) = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Embellishments))(embels)

    For Each em As Embellishments In emblist
        Count = Count + 1
    Next

Catch ex As Exception

    errormessage = ex.Message

End Try
```

BUt I get the error 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation'

Comment: The code works fine for me - both my version and yours.  What does `VB NET 2.0` mean?  You have to be using NET Framework 3.5 or higher since that is when `JavaScriptSerializer` was introduced.  hang on - your class is messed up.

Comment: I've declared all the private vars as integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
Dim emblist As List(Of Embellishments) = jss.Deserialize(Of Embellishments)(embels)
```

You are telling the `Deserializer` it is acting on an `Embellishments` object, but trying to catch the result in a *collection* object.  The error message is telling you that if you are saying that the string is a single object, it cant deserialize to a List of them.  In other words, `Embellishments` is not the same thing as a `List(of Embellishments)`.

Since there *is* more than one object in the string, the correct syntax is (I called mine `Basket`):

```
Dim emblist = jss.Deserialize(Of List(Of Basket))(embels)
```

In VS2010 and beyond, you can use Option Infer to assign the type.  This is also valid and will create an array of Basket Items:

```
Dim emblist = jss.Deserialize(Of Basket())(embels)
```

**More Importantly** you should turn on Option Strict.  This results in nonsense:

```
Private _ProductEmbellishmentID As Integer
Public Property ProductEmbellishmentID() As String
```

The backing field Type doesnt match the property Getter/Setter type and will result in mayhem.  Change the `Property` statements to match the type of the private backing fields.  Again, after VS2010 you can reduce all that boilerplate code with autoimplement properties:

```
Public Class Basket
    Public Property BasketItemID As Integer
    Public Property ProductEmbellishmentID As Integer
    Public Property EmbellishmentText As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal

End Class
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Makes sense. But I get an error when I try it. Can't see how to add code here so I'll add it below

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Yes your answer is correct, it was the mismatch of types causing the error. Thanks a lot for your help!